"Mechanism of Substitution" captured by λ-calculus
I am reading Type Theory and Formal Proof: An Introduction by Nederpelt and Geuvers.
In the Foreword, there is the following, which I quote:

Frege did not get far with his intended formalisation of mathematics: he used an inconsistent foundation. In 1910 Whitehead and Russell
introduced types to remedy this. These authors made proofs largely formal,
except that substitutions still had to be understood and performed by the
reader. In 1940 Church published a system with types, based on a variant of
those of Whitehead and Russell, in which the mechanism of substitution was
captured by lambda-terms and conversion.

To put it briefly, I was wondering what exactly is meant by 'substitutions being understood and performed by the reader'. To elaborate a little bit:

I think that when presenting a logic with its axioms and rules of inference, especially as a foundation, one needs to make sure that these axioms and rules of inference are 'obviously computable / doable' by anyone. I don't think that this notion can be made more precise - we are talking about foundations after all, and we want to start from somewhere. So, is the issue just that Whitehead and Russell thought substitution was 'obviously computable', while Church 'lowered the abstraction' to 'implement' substitution in terms of more basic 'obviously computable operations' like string comparison, etc.?

It would also be interesting for me to make this a little more concrete with an example. A potentially confusing substitution rule in Whitehead and Russell's system and how Church's λ-calculus makes things simpler, perhaps?



The $\lambda$-calculus is a language with only three kinds of terms: variables ranging over $x, y, z, \dots$, abstractions $\lambda x. M$ given a variable $x$ and a term $M$, and applications $MN$ given terms $M, N$.
The abstraction operator $\lambda x$ binds the occurrences of $x$ in $M$, provided an inner abstraction does not already bind them.
For instance, in the term
$$\color{green}{x} (\color{red}{\lambda}x. (\color{red}{x}y \,\color{blue}{\lambda} x. \color{blue}{y})$$
the green occurrence of $x$ and the only occurrence of $y$ are free (that is, not bound to any abstraction), the red (resp. blue) occurrence of $x$ is bound to the red (resp. blue) abstraction.
This language is endowed with a rewrite rule $\to_\beta$ (a binary relation over terms) called $\beta$-reduction and defined as $(\lambda x.M)N \to_\beta M[N/x]$, where $M[N/x]$ is the term obtained from $M$ by substituting $N$ for the free occurrences of $x$. For instance,
$$\big(\lambda x. x (\lambda x. (x y \,\lambda x. y)\big)\lambda z.z
\to_\beta 
\big(x (\lambda x. (x y \,\lambda x. y)\big)[\lambda z.z/x] = \lambda z.z (\lambda x. (x y \,\lambda x. y)$$
Despite its simplicity, the $\lambda$-calculus is a very powerful language: it is Turing complete (where $\beta$-reduction plays the role of a computational step) and strictly related to logic and proof systems via the Curry-Howard correspondence.
But to make it work, the substitution operation quickly introduced above should be defined properly.
To understand that, let us grasp the intuition behind the $\lambda$-calculus.
The $\lambda$-calculus can be seen as a world where everything is a function. A variable $x$ stands for a generic function, an application $MN$ stands for the application of the function $M$ to the argument $N$ (which is, in turn, a function!), and an abstraction $\lambda x.M$ stands for a function that maps $x$ to the term $M$ (which, in turn, may depend on $x$ and other free variables): said differently, if $M = M(x,y_1, \dots, y_n)$ is a term depending on the free variables $x, y_1, \dots, y_n$, then $\lambda x.M$ is the function $x \mapsto M(x,y_1, \dots, y_n)$. For instance,
$$\begin{align}
\lambda x.x &\text{ stands for the identity function } x \mapsto x \text{ (it outputs the input)} 
\\
\lambda x.y &\text{ stands for the constant function } x \mapsto y \text{ (it outputs $y$ for any input)} 
\end{align}$$
Putting this intuition together with the definition of $\beta$-reduction, we get that (suppose that $\mathbf{5}$ is a term representing the natural number $5$):

$(\lambda x.x)\mathbf{5} \to_\beta x[\mathbf{5}/x] = \mathbf{5}$, indeed the term $(\lambda x.x)\mathbf{5}$ is the application of the identity function $x \mapsto x$ to the argument $5$, which yields $5$;

$(\lambda x.y)\mathbf{5} \to_\beta y[\mathbf{5}/x] = y$, indeed the term $(\lambda x.y)\mathbf{5}$ is the application of the constant function $x \mapsto y$ to the argument $5$, which yields $y$.


Now, here is the problem with substitution as introduced above (let us call it naive substitution). Consider the constant function $\lambda x.y$ mapping any argument to $y$. If another variable $z$ substitutes for $y$ in that term, it would be reasonable to expect that the new term is a constant function mapping any argument to $z$. Formally,
$$(\lambda x.y)[z/y] = \lambda x.z
$$
Everything looks fine, except for one case, when $z = x$. Indeed, we would have
$$(\lambda x.y)[x/y] = \lambda x.x
$$
that is, if we replace $y$ with $x$ we completely change the semantics of the term $\lambda x.y$, we do not get anymore a term representing a constant function to $x$ (as we would expect), but the identity function.
This phenomenon, called capture of variables, is very inconvenient and annoying for several reasons.
It happens because if we define $M[N/x]$ as naively substituting $N$ for the free occurrences of $x$ in $M$, the free variables of $N$ can be captured by (that is, end up under the scope of) the binders in $M$.
The solution adopted by Church when he introduced the $\lambda$-calculus is to discard the naive substitution and adopt a more sophisticated notion of substitution, called capture avoiding. There are two steps.

$\alpha$-equivalence: Terms are identified up to the renaming of bound variables, which become dummies as in the notion of integral in mathematical analysis ($\int_a^b x^2 dx$ is the same as $\int_a^b z^2dz$). For instance, the term $\lambda x.x$ is the same as $\lambda z.z$, and the term $\lambda x.y$ is the same as $\lambda z.y$, in both cases we renamed the bound variable $x$ with $z$.

capture-avoiding substitution: Before performing the substitution $M[N/x]$, we should take a representative of $M$ up to $\alpha$-equivalence whose whose bound variables are not free in $N$. Then we perform the substitution $M[N/x]$ on this representative of $M$.
For instance,
$$(\lambda x.y)[x/y] = (\lambda z.y)[x/y] = \lambda z.x = \lambda y.x \neq \lambda x.x$$


Capture-avoiding substitution solves the problem above with naive substitution: when performing a substitution on free variables in a constant function, we still get a constant function as expected, and we are sure that we cannot get the identity function anymore.

The problem of capturing variables when performing a substitution also occurs in first-order logic. Consider for instance the formula $\exists x .\, y< x$: if we replace $y$ with $x$ naively, we get the formula $ \exists x \, x < x$, which has a completely different meaning from the one of the formula before the substitution. The problem is that we want to replace $y$ with the free variable $x$, which is bound in the formula  $\exists x.\, y< x$ where we want to perform the substitution.
According to the capture-avoiding substitution, we identifies formulas up to $\alpha$-equivalence and we get:
$$
(\exists x. \, y < x)[x/y] = (\exists z. \, y< z)[x/y] = \exists z .\, x< z = \exists y. \, x< y
$$

Thanks for the detailed answer and explanation. I think that while the first few paragraphs provide good background, the last few paragraphs are probably what answer my question. I think that what you are saying seems to agree with the following statement that I made in the question: that the notion of 'capture-avoiding' substitution is assumed to be 'obviously doable by people' in Whitehead and Russell's logic, while Church's lambda calculus 'implements' it using more primitive 'obviously doable' operations.
